# Manually add scope to html element via JS Ctrl

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I want to create a new element in my controller and then add a scope variable to this. The way I did it, I only see '{{text}}' in the view instead of the variable value of $scope.text.

That's my code so far:

*JS:*

```
var elem = document.getElementById('match-text');
var newElem = document.createElement('span');
newElem.setAttribute('id', 'inner-match-text');
newElem.setAttribute('class', 'ng-binding');
newElem.innerText = '{{text}}';
elem.appendChild(new_elem);
```

*Html:*

```
<h3 id="match-text"></h3>
```

Maybe this is the totally wrong approach, I don't know. Can someone tell me how to do this properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it necessary to use quotes?

```
newElem.innerText = $scope.text;
```

Comment: Now I just see this '${$scope.text}', so does not work either

Comment: are you using backticks or regular single quotes? you need to use backticks: `

Comment: when I use backticks, I get the error message 'string templates are not supported by current js version'

Comment: So I guess you're using something lower than ES6? What about not using any quotes at all? I've changed my answer.